# redirect from jsp in struts2 application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I am creating a web application on tomcat in framework struts2. I am using intercepters to maintain user session by saving user object in session. Intercepters work fine in order to check user object in session when there is call to action but there are some jsp as well in my application and these jsp can be called directly by url. In this case i want to redirect user to login page if there is no user object in session. Currently i am using sendRedirect method i jsp to redirect to login page. Could you please tell me if these is any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; don't directly access JSP pages. Doing so is counter to what's appropriate in an MVC app.

Comment: Could you please explain..i am new in this.

Comment: @Shobhan There shouldn't be any direct access to JSP pages, not sure what else to say.

Comment: @Shobhan JSPs should go somewhere under the `/WEB-INF` directory so they cannot be directly accessed.

Comment: As @Dave Newton suggested your app not following MVC redirecting to login page done by interceoptor which you can implement a common logic for all pages.

Comment: @DaveNewton: i tried to put jsps in /WEB-INF but it does not work :(

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV: Could you please suggest where i should put my jsp to follow MVC redirectiond to login.

Comment: @Shobhan Saying something "doesn't work" doesn't help anybody diagnose what might be wrong.

Comment: @Shobhan... For fun add struts2-conventions-plugin jar to your classpath and put all your "directly accessible jsps" under "WEB-INF/content" when this works, please look up the conventions plugin to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=XmlAction">
    </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

In Url you can mention your action name which in turn call your jsp result page directly.

Answer (score 0):

"Wrap" those JSP pages with some simple actions like:

The struts.xml way:

```
<action name="example">
    <result>example.jsp</result>
</action>
```

or the Convention plugin way, create a class like this:

```
class ExampleAction extends ActionSupport {
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return "example"; // provided example.jsp is in /WEB-INF/content/
    }
}
```

And then whenever you were linking to `example.jsp`, use `example.action`

Comment: I tried struts.xml way..but it is not able to find example.jsp

Comment: @Shobhan Where *is* `example.jsp`?

Comment: For that case, example.jsp should be in the root of your web content, at the same level as WEBE-INF. or if it's somewhere else try changing the result part `<result>/WEB-INF/jsp/example.jsp</result>` or `<result>/somewhere/else/example.jsp</result>` accordingly.